# Highlight menu item and its submenu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have this css code and I need to do this:
I have a dropdown menu with 5 items.
Item1 (root)
-Item2
-Item3
-Item4
-Item5

When I'm inside the page for example "Item4" I need that the "Item4" menu item and the "Item1 (root)" menu item are highlighted with a same color.

Thanks so much.

```css
.menu-container{
}

.de-menu {
  color:#333;
  font-family:'Ovo';
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:13px;
  letter-spacing:3px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  float:right;
}

.de-menu {
  display:inline-block;
   padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
   height:93px;
}

.de-menu li {
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}

.de-menu a {
  display:block;
  padding:35px 14px 34px 14px; 
  line-height:30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}


.de-menu .current-menu-item a{
  color:#e8c694;
}

.de-menu .current-menu-parent a{
  color:#e8c694;
}

/*.de-menu .active a {
  color:#red;
}*/

.de-menu li ul{
 box-shadow: 0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 margin-left:25px;
 padding:0;
}

.de-menu li li {
 font-size:12px;
 letter-spacing:normal;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}


.de-menu li li a{
 padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
 background:#64483E;
 border-top:none;
}

.de-menu a:hover {
  background:#64483E;
}

.de-menu li li a:hover{
 border-top:none;
}

.de-menu li li a:hover {
  background:url(../images/dotblack30.png) #513D32;
}

.de-menu li ul {
  width:170px;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:-25px;
  z-index:10;
  display:none;
  text-align:left;
}


.de-menu li li {
  display:block;
  float:none;
}

.de-menu li li ul{
 margin-left:0;
}


.de-menu li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

.de-menu li ul ul {
  left:100%;
  top:0px;
}

.de-menu li:hover a {
 background:#64483E;
}


.de-menu select {padding:10px; height:36px; font-size:14px; border:none; background:#513D32; color:#fff;}
.de-menu select option{padding:10px;}
```

Comment: you don't have any html in your post, so its unclear what html structure you're using for that menu

Comment: http://www.artabout.it/musciara - this is a private link

Comment: Looking with inspector tools, you'll notice that you have some active classes on the current active page/subpage etc. that you can use to style those links accordingly: current-menu-parent - current-menu-item

Comment: Use `<a>` tag, and style it with `a:hover`.

Comment: if that wordpress site is the one you're talking about, it has everything you need - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes

Answer (score 0):

(this style is already in stylesheet around line 275, so just need to add background color)

```
.de-menu .current-menu-parent a {
 background: #64483E;
}
```

(this would be to add to style sheet):

```
.de-menu .current-menu-parent .sub-menu .current-menu-item a {
 background: url("../images/dotblack30.png") #513D32;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I try this but don't work. The question is: I have a drop menu with 5 links: Rooms - Camere con vista - Case con vista mare - Suite - Depandance. When I'm on Suite, the item menu Suite and Rooms must be highlight brown and the other remain white.  When I'm on Depandance, the item menu Depandance and Rooms must be highlight brown and the other white etc. etc.
This is the link: http://www.artabout.it/musciara

Comment: I was able to change it through the console inspector and it worked for me

Comment: Please, can you copy paste these changes here? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In my CSS file, "active" class has highlighting css values like

```
"background-color: #FFFFFF"
```

I'm using these in each page:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("PAGE_MENU_NAME_1").className = "active";
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("PAGE_MENU_NAME_2").className = "active";
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("PAGE_MENU_NAME_3").className = "active";
</script>
```

Use one of above for which page you are viewing.

This is my master page like "Menu.php"

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li id="PAGE_MENU_NAME_1"><a href="page1.php">PAGEMENUNAME1"</a></li>
   <li id="PAGE_MENU_NAME_1"><a href="page2.php">PAGEMENUNAME2"</a></li>
   <li id="PAGE_MENU_NAME_3"><a href="page3.php">PAGEMENUNAME3"</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope you get what I said.